# Upload content to facebook without prompt

Tags: php, api, facebook, permissions

I am working on a PHP application that gets its input (image/text) from a mobile device and posts this to various social networks.

Now, I'm having some problems figuring out how to post to facebook WITHOUT facebook prompting me for permission. I am the only user so I can add my username and password in the code or I can have facebook prompt me one time to accept my php app to post items.

Does anyone have experience with this or some interesting links ?

Answer (score 1):

you must prompt your users to grant [extended permissions](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permission) for posting images and text ("publish_stream") and for times when the user is offline or doesn't have an active session ("offline_access").

Answer (score 0):

It is not permitted for you to screen-scrap - basically what you would do with your hard-coded username and password. I would first look at your Privacy Settings for the application you are writing on Facebook and see if there is an option for photos.